# VueJs website nested in a React Website

Tags: nginx, web-hosting, nginx-reverse-proxy

**Hello,**

This is a weird question i know :D

I'm hosting a website powered by React at `domain.io`

I'm hosting a portfolio powered by VueJs at `portfolio.domain.io`

I'm trying to configure nginx so that : `domain.io/portfolio` Displays the content of `portfolio.domain.io`

I tried a lot of things like proxy_pass or redirect but it seems that i'm doing this wrong...

currently i have this in my config :

```
location = /portfolio {
  rewrite ^ https://portfolio.domain.io$request_uri permanent;
}
```

also tried :

```
  location /portfolio {
    proxy_pass  https://portfolio.domain.io$request_uri;
    proxy_set_header Host  portfolio.domain.io;
  }
```

Do you have any idea on what i could try or is this even possible ?

Thanks !

EDIT : (full config)

```

```
server {

        root /var/www/ivan/website/dist;
        index index.html index.php ndex.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name domain.io _;


    location = /portfolio {
            rewrite ^ https://portfolio.domain.io$request_uri permanent;            
    }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
            expires 15d;
        }

        location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
            expires 30d;
        }
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2; 
    listen 443 ssl http2; 
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = domain.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name domain.io _;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

```

Comment: Can you provide your entire server directive for better understanding of what are the things not been correctly setup? BTW, you also needs a wildcard SSL certificate for *.domain.com. If you only has a single-domain SSL certificate, it won't work.

Comment: I've go a certificate for domain.io and portfolio.domain.io, isn't that enough ?
(i also add the full config in the main post)